# How to call a string array in a if/else statement in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, if-statement

I'm a beginner in javascript and I trying to call a string array in an if/else statement. This is what I have. Which works fine, but is there a shorter way to execute this. I don't want to use any other method. I just want to stick to if/else statement.

enter code here

```
    var welcomeMessage = prompt("what is your name?").toLowerCase();
    var names = ["brad", "elena", "simon", "stella", "stasia", "sylvester", "sinclare"];

    if(welcomeMessage === names[0] || welcomeMessage === names[1] || welcomeMessage === names[2] || welcomeMessage === names[3] || welcomeMessage === names[4] || welcomeMessage === names[5] || welcomeMessage === names[6]) {
    alert("Your Authorized!");
  } else {
    alert("Signup for free!");
}
```

Comment: "I'm a beginner in javascript", "Is there a shorter way?", "I only want to use if/else"...  Yes there is a better/shorter way, it does not use if/else. Why the constraint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use indexOf method.

```
    var welcomeMessage = prompt("what is your name?").toLowerCase();
    var names = ["brad", "elena", "simon", "stella", "stasia", "sylvester", "sinclare"];

    if(names.indexOf(welcomeMessage) >= 0) {
    alert("Your Authorized!");
  } else {
    alert("Signup for free!");
}
```

Comment: "I don't want to use any other method."

Comment: @JordanS And? I just made your check in "if statment" shorter.

Comment: @Smiranin, thanks for the help. That worked. I'm currently taking some Javascript online courses and before I move on to the next level I wanted to get a good handle on variables, strings, operators, numbers, if/else Math.random and prompts. indexOf was mentioned in the course.